# Ubuntu 12.10 Unity Performance - Dragging a GLXGEARS through the Desktop

Tags: unity, upgrade, 12.10, performance

I've been using the `12.10` since It was launched.

I have a `I7` with a `Geforce GT520` running `304.43` driver version.

With `12.04`, using a lot of `Compiz` animation, I could drag a window running `glxgears` quickly through the desktop, but now, using `12.10`, is almost impossible to do this. It hangs a lot. Actually, is almost impossible even try resizing another window if a instance of `glxgears` is running. The cube performance is terrible too.

I'm not sure, but seems that this new `Unity` and `Compiz` are worst than previous version. The conky also is abnormal, it often looses its transparency, showing a dark background instead. It's not a conky configuration, I have tried all possible configurations.

Using `gnome3` or `gnome-shell` I have the same issues.

It only does not happen while using `gnome 2d` (without effects).

Are you feeling the same poor speed and motion quality on `12.10`?

I had also tried to uninstall the `unity`, `compiz`, almost everything, but nothing returned the great desktop performance of Unity on `12.04`.

My boot time, using a SSD is around 18 seconds. I think that it could be better, too.

Thank's,

David

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu and thanks for your question. If you could point out a bit more how we can help you, it will get more likely that the community can find an answer for you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the open source drivers rather than the proprietary nidia drivers. Phoronix has shown benchmarks showing that the Open Source drivers works better in 12.10 than the proprietary ones. Please visit this link for several articles related to this: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=category&item=Display%20Drivers
Also, this article may be informative for you too: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_unity_68&num=1